# How to handle windows path spaces when executing in C

Tags: c, string, windows, path

i have this path which I like to execute :

```
 "C:/Program Files(x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat"
```

i feeding this string into C  exe function

```
int exe(const char *str, ...) {
    char buf[1024];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);
    vsprintf(buf, str, args);
    va_end(args);
    printf("%s\n\n", buf);
    return system(buf);
}
```

but im getting :
after calling :

```
 char* it = "\"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvarsall.bat\"";
exe(it)

'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

how can i overcome the spaces in the path ?

Comment: Please post the line where you call `exe`, preferrably with a [mcve].

Comment: updated question

Comment: it compiles file and yes it is C file sorry

Comment: updated question

Comment: When you're this close to the OS it's usually best to drop a cross-platform approach. Instead, call `CreateProcess` on cmd.exe passing it appropriate arguments. Alternatively you can launch a batch script using `ShellExecuteEx`.

Answer (score 0):

The system does not know that you are referring to one path that contains spaces.

Either replace spaces with escaped spaces " " -> "\ ".

Or envelop the path in double quotes by adding escaped quotes in front and back ".